# Running NVDA screen-reader on a single application?

Tags: screen-readers, nvda

I know that's not the primary use or intended behavior of NVDA, but as a developer it would be amazing to be able to limit NVDA readout to a single window/application.

In its current state I'm forced to close and relaunch NVDA every time I switch between browser and VSCode to make some rapid changes and test.

Or maybe someone has an idea on how to efficiently deal with Screenreader testing in real-time while developing?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this with the current version, but there are two ways you could accomplish this with either a wait or with some effort:  1.  Put in a feature request to add a command line switch or other way of telling NVDA to only look at a specific set of processes like myapp.exe 2.  Download the source code from github and modify it yourself, and optionally offer your changes as a patch

Comment: It is extremely annoying as a developer to have NVDA read everything i do besides my browser. Is there an option to turn off NVDA temporarily via shortcut without closing it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing because, obviously, this is not the intended use case of NVDA.

That said, as [@thg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795423/thg) asked in the comments, there is in fact a way to disable screen reading temporarily, so you can alt-tab, code something, alt-tab back. From [NVDA docs](https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html?#RunningNVDA):

> Toggle Speech Mode | **NVDA+s** | Toggles speech mode between speech, beeps and off.

Where NVDA is the modifier, which is ***insert*** by default (also ***numpad zero***, if num lock is off)".
Note that it cycles 3 values: *Speech* -> *Off* -> *Beeps*.

Answer (score 1):

I am an NVDA user and volunteer contributor.

The topic is a bit old, but here is what I recommend to have NVDA speaking only in the tested application:

- Be sure not to be in the application that you want to test, e.g. open Windows Explorer.
- Right click NVDA icon in systray, select "Preferences", "Settings"
- In the "Speech" category, click the "Change" button to change the synthesizer used
- Select the "No speech" synthesizer and press twice "OK" to exit the dialogs
- Open the application you want to test (or your browser if you are testing a webpage)
- Right click NVDA icon in systray and click "Configuration profiles..."
- Click "New"
- Select "Current application (yourApplicationProcessName)
- Press OK and Close
- Right click NVDA icon in systray, select "Preferences", "Settings"
- Right click NVDA icon in systray, select "Preferences", "Settings"
- In the "Speech" category, click the "Change" button to change the synthesizer used
- Select a synthesizer, e.g. "Windows OneCore voices" and press twice "OK" to exit the dialogs

From now on, you will have NVDA muted in all applications, except in the application you are testing. Note that NVDA is still running in the other applications (e.g. shortcuts are still operating), but at least, you will not be bothered by voice feedback.